# reloading tableView of one view controller from a pushed view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, tableview

I've got a Parse background block that uploads some data. This occurs in a view controller (lets call it `addDataViewController`) that was pushed onto another view controller (where my table view is, lets call that `tableViewController`). I need to reload that tableView when the data finishes uploading. Ive got a navigation controller embedded in my storyboard so ive tried doing

```
//In addDataViewController
//when the data finishes uploading
self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

but for some reason the viewController stack was `nil`.

Then I tried referencing `tableViewController` as a property of the `addDataViewController` in prepare for segue of `tableViewController`. I added a `tableViewController` property to my h file of `addDataViewController`

```
//in prepare for segue of tableViewController
dataViewController.tableViewController = self;
```

then referenced that objects `tableView` and called `reloadData`, but nothing seemed to happen

```
[self.tableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

I thought for sure that would have worked, but it didnt. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one approach is to use notifications. in your addDataViewController you would fire a notification, when the update is done:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateDone" object:nil];
```

in your tableViewController you would subscribe to the notification in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doSomething)
                                             name:@"UpdateDone"
                                           object:nil];
```

and then:

```
-(void)doSomething {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: hmm the notification is getting set in my dataViewController but the selector isnt firing in my tableViewController.

Comment: actually it did, still nothing though. Its like my tableView just wont reload for some reason

Comment: i think, before you reload the tableview of have to update the datasource. i think you have an array to fill your tableview, this you have to build new inside doSomething before reloading.

Comment: that was it. forgot to grab my data again. Thanks for your help man

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing view controller then you must use [self.addChildViewController:tableViewController.view];

hope this will help.